# Show $\beta$ is a basis for subspace $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm working on problems in the section about dimensions of subspaces associated with a matrix.

The problem states to use the results of the section to show that $\beta$ is a basis for the subspace $V$.

$\beta = {[0, 1, 4], [4,  -7,  0]}$

$V =$ {$[-s+t, 2s-t, s+3t]$$\epsilon$$\mathbb{R}^3$: r, s, and t are scalars}

How would I solve a problem like this ?

Comment: The question is kind of hard to answer since we don't know what "the results of the section" are.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the two vectors are linearly independent and belong to $V$; moreover $V$ is not the whole of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

If you want to use matrices and linear maps, you can consider the linear map
$$
f\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^3,\qquad
f([s,t])=[-s+t, 2s-t, s+3t]
$$
Compute its associate matrix and see whether the two given vectors belong to the image. Then you're basically done.

Comment: What would be the first step I should take from there?

Answer (score 0):

If $V$ has dimension $n$ and $v_1,...,v_n$ are $n$ linearly independent vectors in $V$, then they are a basis of $V$. You can start working from there.